# Grabbing the last names of players in array using split, splice

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, split, splice

## Objective

I'm trying to get just the last names of the players in a series of spans and then be able to store those lastNames in their own variable `var lastNameA`, `var lastNameB` ...

Here is an example of some of the names, `Pierre Turgeon`, `Larry Patey`, `Kelly Shattenkirk`, `Barret Jackman`, `Alex Pietrangelo`, `Jacques Plante` and **in one special case, the person's last name is `St. Marseille`**

## scripts.js

In many cases, I will want the even number items in the array, but with St. Marseille, I want both the `St.` and `Marseille`

```
    // Grabs the names of all the players in the span
    // Then, it joins the names together with a comma and a space
    var fullNames = $("li span").map(function(){
        return $(this).text();
    }).get().join(", ");

    // This breaks a name into their first name and last name
    fullNames.split(" ");
```

Comment: you could split the string into an array and then get the last index in case they have middle names and that should get you the surname

Comment: unless you know in advance how many parts represent firstnames and lastnames you need the source text to specify which are which. Many cultures allow for 2+ tokens for lastnames and various standards determining the dominant one.

Comment: I'm just curious, is this when they register and you plan on using their registered name and splitting it? Wouldn't it be easier to have separate input forms for the registration - will make it easier knowing that you will get the users surname from one field

Comment: @Torean Can you post a code example

Comment: @Torean It's a best of list of 50 players, so I already know all of the names and I'm just trying to grab the last names for this specific use case

Comment: interesting, I still think on registration it will be better to just have a field to have the separate and then use them where needed across the game, you will save a lot of time

Comment: Definitely best to capture the "fore name" and "family name" separately wherever possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can split only at the first space, but then you'll run into trouble with names like John Steven Murphy, where the last name is just "Murphy." Then there are names like Gerard van der Sanden or Angelina de la Vega and such, where there is not just one space but two in the family name.

Bottom-line, it's always going to be wrong for certain inputs if you don't have a clear delimiter.

But if you work on the basis that the "first" name won't have any spaces (which is a flawed assumption):

```
var lastNames = $("li.span").map(function() {
    var name = $(this).text();
    var index = name.indexOf(" ");
    return index == -1 ? name : name.substring(index + 1);
}).get();
```

```js
var lastNames = $("li.span").map(function() {
  var name = $(this).text();
  var index = name.indexOf(" ");
  return index == -1 ? name : name.substring(index + 1);
}).get();
console.log(lastNames);
console.log("Note that it gets John Steven Murphy wrong, see answer text for details.");
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="span">Pierre Turgeon</li>
  <li class="span">Larry Patey</li>
  <li class="span">Kelly Shattenkirk</li>
  <li class="span">Barret Jackman</li>
  <li class="span">Alex Pietrangelo</li>
  <li class="span">Jacques Plante</li>
  <li class="span">Michel St. Marseille</li>
  <li class="span">Gerard van der Sanden</li>
  <li class="span">Angelina de la Vega</li>
  <li class="span">John Steven Murphy</li>
</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: When I run this snippet, I get "undefined" in the console.

Comment: @AndrewNguyen: I don't think I had a snippet in the answer until just now, and the one that's there works.

Comment: In this case, I know all the names of the 50 hockey players. But it's good that you noted some of the use cases that I might encounter in other projects when dealing with names

Comment: I was hoping you could elaborate more on what's happening in this line `return index == -1 ? name : name.substring(index + 1);`

Comment: @AndrewNguyen: If `indexOf` doesn't find a space, it returns -1. So that's returning the full name if no spaces are found. Otherwise, it's returning only what follows the space.

Answer (score 0):

Using ES 6 destructuring:

```
let [first, middle, end] = str.split(' ');
if (!end) {
  end = middle;
  middle = '';
}
```

As noted in the comments, this is fragile. Any answer you get here is [going to be fragile](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). You will have to tread carefully in any situation involving names, but for simple inputs this should work ok.

Comment: That's **awfully** fragile.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder so is any string handling solution short of a full parser or a special delimiting character like an invisible unicode character.

Answer (score 0):

I think threw a map function you just need tonsplit slice and join like this :

```
 var persons = ["Pierre Turgeon", "Larry Patey", "Kelly Shattenkirk", "Barret Jackman", "Alex Pietrangelo", "Jacques Plante", "Thierry St Marseille"];
 var names = persons.map(person => person.split(" ").slice(1).join(" "));
 console.log(names);
```